# How do I use .htaccess to force www. while using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to force a www. prefix on my website by using a .htaccess 301 redirect. I am currently trying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which normally works, but I am using Zend Framework which causes all requests to be redirected back to http://www.mysite.com/index.php regardless of the initial request.

For example...

```
http://mysite.com/blog, 
http://mysite.com/contact,
http://mysite.com/blog/this-is-my-article,
```

Will all be redirected to http://www.mysite.com/index.php

However, if I initially request a specific file, such as...

```
http://mysite.com/some-file.htm
```

The redirect works properly, redirecting to http://www.mysite.com/some-file.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first time, don't forget to enable the rewriting ("RewriteEngine on").
The last line is important if you use Zend Framework.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|php|js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|rss|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php
```

Now the url...

```
http://mysite.com/some-file.htm
```

... redirect to http://www.mysite.com/some-file.htm but use the index.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to ignore sub-domains when re-directing to www.

http://www.theblogaholic.com/2011/01/16/force-www-using-htaccess-except-for-subdomains/